# Colab and desktop installation (Anaconda) builds different layer output shape for the same deconvolutional neural net

Tags: keras, anaconda, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, layer

I have the same exact network in Colab and desktop but the output of layers are strangely different. the network is defined as:

```
latent_dim = 128

generator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,)),
        # We want to generate 128 coefficients to reshape into a 7x7x128 map
        layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 128),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Reshape((7, 7, 128)),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(1, (7, 7), padding="same", activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
    name="generator",
)
generator.summary()
```

The input 128 noise samples then it is multiplied in Dense layer to 7x7x128, then reshaped to 7,7,128. then in 1st convT to 14,14,128 then to 28,28,128 and finally to 28,28,1.
Colab produces the correct structure:

```
Model: "generator"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 6272)              809088    
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_10 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 6272)              0         
                                                                 
 reshape_2 (Reshape)         (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DT  (None, 14, 14, 128)      262272    
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_11 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 14, 14, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DT  (None, 28, 28, 128)      262272    
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_12 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 28, 28, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 1)         6273      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,339,905
Trainable params: 1,339,905
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

but copy pasting the same code in Spyder (Anaconda) it produces:

```
Model: "generator"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 6272)              809088    
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 6272)              0         
                                                                 
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTra  (None, 128, 14, 256)     14464     
 nspose)                                                         
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 128, 14, 256)      0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DT  (None, 128, 28, 512)     262272    
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 128, 28, 512)      0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 1, 28, 512)        6273      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,092,097
Trainable params: 1,092,097
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________
```

what's wrong in my desktop that cause this difference?

Comment: check versions of libraries

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution: the same exact library i.e. Keras on Colab thinks that your data channels are the last dimension of your input. the same exact library on your local PC thinks differently so add data_format='channels_last' to the argument of conv2D and deconv2D layers and it works until next bug!

Comment: The onus is really on you to make sure you are using the right version of the library. Especially in fields where progress is rapid, you can expect new versions of libraries to have backwards-incompatible changes.